# I cannot unbake my emission f-curve

Tags: baking, emission

I have a project where emission reacts to an audio file. I have baked the sound to f-curve but it is too jittery, i know you can smooth the key frames using 'smooth keys' but you need to unbake the curve first. I don't know if it's because the keyframe is for emission but i don't get the option to unbake the curve. Would be amazing if someone could clear this up! Thanks:)

Answer (score 0):

When you use the "Bake sound to F-curve", it doesn't create any keyframes. Hence you can't use keyframe-based operators on it.

You can however try baking the sound to fcurve again, but while browsing for the sound file: play with the baking options in the sidebar:

[image: options]

You could try setting the Attack Time to 0.05 for example:

[image: attack time]

Comment: But you can use _Un-Bake Curve_ from the _Key_ menu and then you have keyframes. That's what I usually do with baked sound. But in the question @fowcaster says the option for unbaking the curve isn't there: "_but i don't get the option to unbake the curve_". Now the question would be why this is, It's not because it's an _Emission_ value - that doesn't matter.

Answer (score 0):

I know you said the option isn't there, just for recap I'll say how it should work:

First of all, in the *Graph Editor* make sure you have **selected** the curve which the sound is baked to. Then in the *Key* menu choose *Un-Bake Curve* and you'll get keyframes so that you can smooth the curve.

(I was going to insert pictures here, but there seems to be a server error)

Just be aware that when you un-bake the curve only the part from start to end frame will get keyframes, the rest is discarded. If you later maybe want to use a different part of the sound curve, make sure you set start and end frame so that it covers the complete curve before un-baking. Afterwards you can switch it back to whatever you want.

As I said, this is just for recap. This also works on *Emission*, so if you are sure you have selected the correct curve and the option still doesn't show up, maybe we'll need the *.blend file to investigate further.